# Can AMPScript retrieve the full POST body?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, landing-page

I'm trying to do some interaction with FB Webhook and it says to retrieve the POST Body that is sent as a JSON Object.

AMPScript has the REQUESTPARAMETER, but it requires a parameter name. Is there a way to retrieve the full POST Body in AMPScript?

The tutorials are in PHP.

```
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

Comment: did you ever find the answer to this?